# Incomprehensible ENOMEM on fopen

Tags: c++, c, io

A daemon often enough creates files for writing. Sometimes fopen/open/ofstream call fails with

```
errno == ENOMEM
```

All memory monitors show memory is enough. No any anothers memory errors. Which memory kind is insufficiently?

upd:
Сonfirm is unstable.
Free inodes are enough.
std::ofstream::open() uses open64() inside. So ENOMEM means [The path argument names a STREAMS file and the system is unable to allocate resources.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [Insufficient kernel memory was available](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).
Ok. fileno count in dump ~ 800, setrlimit(65K). Any ideas?

upd2:
ENOMEM occured on rename

Comment: ENOMEM is about storage, not memory. So you are out of actual storage for the file.

Comment: According to [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) it's caused by 'insufficient storage space'.

Comment: Maybe `perror()` can shed a light?

Comment: Is it possible that there are really a lot of files (I mean hundreds of thousands) in the directory that contains the files?

Comment: What is "storage for file"? Why is not ENOSPC?
@Jabberwocky: yes, there are tens or hundreds of files.

Comment: In pursuit of: free disk space is enough.

Comment: So what was the issue? You can post an answer for others to read in the future.

Comment: I've updated question.

Comment: Per the fopen man-page:  "The fopen(), fdopen(), freopen() and fmemopen() functions may also fail and set errno for any of the errors specified for the routine malloc(3)."  ... presumably that is what is happening.  As for why `malloc()` might fail with `ENOMEM`, being genuinely out of RAM is possible, but an equally likely possibility would be that your process's heap is corrupted in a way that causes `malloc()` to fail.  You might run with `valgrind` or similar and see if it picks up any heap corruption issues.

Comment: Yes, valgrind may to help. Thank You.

Comment: Other side, heap corrupt would affect more than single call

Comment: It looks like there is a limit on the number of files that open simultaneously. I've added semaphore for 8 simultaneously opening and no confirmation more. While.